# Switch current rating label: 0.1GPA

Tags: current, switches

I feel like this ought to be a FAQ, but because of the abundance of articles on Grade Point Average coming out of the US, it's extremely difficult to search for. I have a micro switch with rather difficult to read labelling on it, but which clearly shows a current rating of 0.1GPA (and 125 VAC):
[image]
I'm used to seeing a simple 'A' after current ratings. What does the 'GP' stand for in this instance?

Comment: Rest assured: I've never heard about GPA...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To really know, you'd have to have a few hundred dollars to get [access to the CUL 61058-1 document](https://standardscatalog.ul.com/standards/en/standard_61058-1_5). However, it probably stands for General Purpose Amps GPA. The rating is the same as a regular amp, they probably redefine it to differentiate between DC amps and AC amps or to mean both.

[image]
Source: http://www.state-elec.com/honeywell/pdf/MICRO-SWITCH%20V15.pdf

Comment: I see! Thanks very much.

Comment: Do general purpose amps cost less than hand-machined special purpose amps?

Comment: Yes, and you only get them if you live in the US, there are no general purpose amps outside of the US, only regular amps

Answer (score 2):

Bottom of page 17 of this [Farnell document](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1971450.pdf) defines it as “GPA – General Purpose Amps (Inductive Load)”.